# Draw Circle at the end of Arc Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

Hello guys I want to make a small circle at the end of the arc in android canvas,
I can draw arc and circle separately but I want to get the position where arc end and want to draw a small circle the,
actually I want to draw the sun angle
here is what I exactly want to do  and where I reach until now..[image: what i want]

[image: what i have done till now]